# Comparative measure: How to compare two sets with the same measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Is there a "comparative" measure to compare two sets with the same measure?

For instance, with "comparative" measure, we might be able to say this:

$\mathbb{N}$ (set of integers) is measure zero compared with $\mathbb{Q}$ (set of rational numbers).

Though both $\mathbb{N}$  and $\mathbb{Q}$  have measure zero, intuitively $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinitely "larger" than $\mathbb{N}$.

One specific version of the above question is:

is it possible to compare two measure zero sets, for example, $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I don't believe this question is "unclear". They are asking if there is a way of saying that natural numbers are "smaller" than rationals with some measure

Comment: @ZacharySelk I disagree.  The question first asks about sets that are measure zero (with respect to Lebesgue measure, one presumes, though that isn't made clear, either), then asks about a "comparative" measure, which I took to mean a measure that can be used to compare any two Lebesgue null-sets, but which could also be interpreted as you have done.  I don't think that the question is at all clear.

Comment: @XanderHenderson "then asks about a "comparative" measure, which I took to mean a measure that can be used to compare any two Lebesgue null-sets, but which could also be interpreted as you have done." aren't those the same thing?

Comment: @ZacharySelk Perhaps it would be better if I said that *I* saw at least two different ways of interpreting the question: (1) is there a single measure on $\mathbb{R}$ (or, perhaps, the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$) which can be used to compare Lebesgue nullsets? or (2) is there a nonzero measure on $\mathbb{Q}$ that give $\mathbb{N}$ zero measure?  Maybe you don't think that the ambiguity is there, but I am confused by the question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I agree that those are two ways of interpreting the question. I interpreted it a third way - is there either one?

Comment: For specifically subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, the [Natural Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) is often used. This appears in Sieving Theory (within Number Theory) quite often.   So, this is used to compare $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ with $\mathbb{N}$, but doesn't work to compare $\mathbb{N}$ with sets larger than it (that I know of).

Comment: Some about the confusion. I was putting two questions in this post, one more general (some theory about "comparative" measure), one more specific (regarding comparing measure zero sets, such as $\mathbb{Q,N}$). As @ZacharySelk pointed out, I would appreciated any comments on either one question.

Comment: There are [many notions of smallness in mathematics](http://www.afo.ulg.ac.be/fb/meeting/genericity/files/Bayart.pdf) --- measure, cardinality, Baire category, Hausdorff and other dimensions, [capacity notions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22small+sets%22+%22potential%20theory%22+capacity), [having a "small" intersection with every (or "most" in some sense) line or plane or some other natural class of objects relevant to the set in question](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-060-01/S0002-9939-1976-0417359-8/), etc.

Comment: @TianLeMa are you interested specifically in defining measures on $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$, or are you interested in general notions of saying that the naturals are “smaller” than the rationals?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I am more interested in the general notion of "comparative" measure, with which we can say the naturals are "smaller" than the rationals, etc.

Comment: @TianLeMa then you may want to avoid using the word “measure”, as it means something very specific, when it seems to me that what you’re looking for is a bit more general than that. The use of the specific term also seems to have steered the discussion in the earlier comments away from the direction you really want, maybe. Anyway, Dave’s comment is a great place to start.

Comment: "*I am more interested in* [...] *the naturals are "smaller" than the rationals*" There are several notions of smallness of countable sets of reals that are often used, and the set of rationals belongs to one of the largest ones (dense in the reals) and the set of integers belongs to one of the smallest ones (a uniformly isolated set). Two smallness notions that fit between these two is having a countable closure and the larger notion of a scattered set (= nowhere dense in each nonempty perfect set; by comparison, "nowhere dense" is equivalent to being nowhere dense in each interval).